# How can I delete some data from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I have this functions to save and get data on it:
to save:

```
try {
        const request = new Request('https://yandexmap-96969-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/locations.json', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(addNewLocation)
            })
        const response = await fetch(request)
        window.location.reload()
        return await response.json()
    } catch (error) {
        alert('Try again: ', error)
        }

//to get:

try {
        const request = new Request('https://yandexmap-96969-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/locations.json', { method: 'get'})
        const response = await fetch(request)
        return await response.json()
    } catch (error) {
        alert('Try again: ', error)
    }
```

And when I use "delete" instead of "get" it deletes the locations folder entirely, but when I use a link with a key at the end of the link, I get an error

Comment: Hello, if my answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the tick icon. [What should I do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) else feel free to ask further queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make a `DELETE` request at the location you need to delete.

```
curl -X DELETE \
  'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/locations.json'
```

```
const request = new Request('https://yandexmap-96969-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/locations.json', { method: 'DELETE'})
const response = await fetch(request)
return await response.json()
```

I'm not sure about how your database structure looks like but the above request will delete the whole "locations" node. Here's an example:

[image]

If you want to delete only `location2`, then make a delete request at `https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/locations/location2.json`

I'm not sure if there's any specific reason for you to use the REST API but you can try using Firebase [Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). It's easier to use, for example to delete location2:

```
firebase.database().ref("locations/location2").remove()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot to add ".json" at the end of the link

Answer (score 0):

you can use the remove method

```
let userRef = this.database.ref('users/' + userId);
    userRef.remove()
```

Comment: tip : adding code fences can highlight the code and make it better to read (especially if you have a lot of code)

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use the following code

```js
deleteSomeData(id) {
      fetch(
         // don't add .json at [data Name]
        `https://[your FireBase project url]/[data Name (don't add .json)]/${id}.json`,
        {
          method: 'Delete',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      )
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
               // if sucess do something
          } else {
               // if fail throw error
            throw new Error('could not delete data');
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.error = error.message;
          console.log(id);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user item id to delete it like below.

const request = new Request('https://yandexmap-96969-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/locations/<localtion_id>.json', { method: 'delete'})

your location id can be value like this,  -MyB0qQoQuf9lPnwderfg